# LEX: Kanban listview migration

Tags: kanban, lightninglistview

Question regarding the Kanban view for the Object ListView.

I successfully migrated a new object, all its fields, page layouts, record types and the list view from sandbox using a change set. I had a Kanban view setup in the sandbox for one of the list view's, but now in Prod it looks like I have to do it all over again.

Is there a component or something else I need to add to my change set, like a lightning page of Flexi Page, in order for the Kanban setting to come over?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the list view is not there?  If the list view is there, then making it "kanban" is just changing the way you are viewing that list view. Salesforce will 'remember' the way you looked at it last - list, kanban, split.  But I would imagine it defaults back to list when moved through change set.  If you change to kanban, it should remember that moving forward.